# The motion of an object in a slant surface against friction

Tags: kinematics, friction

[image: m stands for the objects mass]
if I take to surfaces slant at the same degree wouldn't there coefficient of friction be different depending on the nature of the surfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F_{friction} = \mu mg\cos(\theta)$ is only true if the surface is set at the exact slope where the block goes from sticking to sliding.  The more generally correct relation, assuming, as you specify, that the block is stationary, is $F_{friction} \leq \mu mg\cos(\theta)$.

So you have done the math right, but interpreted it wrong.  $\mu = \tan(\theta)$ does not imply that the friction is a function of inclination angle, it rather lets you determine the coefficient of friction from the inclination angle at which the block goes from sticking to sliding, or, equivalently, it lets you determine what that special angle is if you know the coefficient of friction.

The wording I've used here ignores the fact that sometimes it is claimed, and taught in intro physics, that the static friction coefficient is greater than the kinetic friction coefficient.

Comment: So can I say if the surface is set at the exact slope where the block goes from sticking to sliding then no matter how sharp or smooth the surface is its coefficent of friction will be given by th equation tan (teta).

Comment: @Hilea Yes indeed

Comment: If that is the case wouldn't we be saying the coefficent of friction is not affected by the roughness of the surface

Comment: To make my quetsion more clear, if you take two inclinded planes one very rough the other very soft and set them to equal angles of elevation and then put objects with the same mass, there would be an angle where the objects will be inbetween sticking and sliding. Are  those angles equal for both the systems. If I am not wrong that is what you told me right? But is that the case in real life?

Comment: No, that is not what I told you.  The angle at which the rough one would start to slide would be steeper.  You don't get to *choose* this angle: it is an attribute of the system.  Since the angle at which the block starts to slide is steeper for the rough plane, you'd calculate a larger coefficient of friction.